# Get more display information for fullcalender event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

currently I am developing a web calendar application with FullCalendar JS. For this application I need to show more information than just the title of the event.

At the moment I just extend the title.

`

```
calendar.addEvent({
  id: event["id"],
  title: event["title"] + "\n" + event["participant"] + "\n" + event["street"] + "\n" + event["zip_city"],
  start: event["startTime"],
  end: event["endTime"],
  color: event["color"]
})
```

`

I just wonder if there is a better and simpler way to do it.

Comment: That way looks pretty simple. Are you unhappy with it in some specific way? We'll probably need some clear definition of "better" before we can give you meaningful help.

Comment: I am unhappy with concatenating the string in that way. In fact It would be great if the font weight could differ in the result. Like the title bold and anything else normal.

Comment: Ah, if you want to alter the appearance of the event, and/or include content from additional properties of the event (instead of concatenating into the title), you can use the event render hooks, which let you alter the html of the event display. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display for details